# Nested enhanced for loop for One-dimensional arrays

Tags: java, for-loop

I'm trying to compare elements with each other in the array. It would be better to do that with enhanced for loop, but I'm not sure how to do that

```
for (int i : a4){
    for (int j=0; j<a4.length; j++){ //how to convert this line to enhanced for loop?
        if(a4[i]+1==a4[j]){
            count++;
        } 
    }
}
```

That's very interesting: when I'm using a regular loop for the first line

`for(int i=0; i<a4.length; i++)...`

the program gives the wrong results. 
what's a mystery? 
or

`for(int i=0; i<a4.length; i++)` not equal to `for (int i : a4)`?!

Comment: Yes they are the same, you've got the syntax right, can you please show the code maybe you got a typo, and if you can show the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with using enhanced loops for both loops:

```
for (int i : a4) {
    for (int j : a4) {
        if (i == j) count++;
    }
}
```

*However*, if you really want to compare only distinct elements of an array with other elements, then you really need the indices which come with regular `for` loops:

```
for (int i=0; i < a4.length-1; ++i) {
    for (int j=i+1; j < a4.length; ++j) {
        if (a4[i] == a4[j]) count++;
    }
}
```

The reason for this is you don't want to compare, e.g., the first element against the first element, because it would always be true.